# Android view, starts element from bottom overlap with header on small screens

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a sample view, where on the top is logo + header divider + some description, and from the bottom starts: Button + some checkboxes, please see image below:

[image]

It looks good on current devices, but on old phones, when screen is small (5 inches for example) - elements overlap:

[image]

View looks like below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<!-- TOP -->

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/loremipsum"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.12"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.50"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/header_divider"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text"
        android:lines="2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- BOTTOM -->

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMobile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/validIDLinearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMobilePhonePicker"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
                android:id="@+id/countryCodePickerId"
                ...
                />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/mobileEditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:hint="elo elo elo"
                android:inputType="phone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mobileText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fragment_terms_and_condition_send_sms" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/validIDLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/consentLinearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewValidIdBottom"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/errorRed"
                android:text="text" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/consentLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/privacyPolicyLinearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/errorRed"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewConsent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fragment_terms_and_condition_consent_VI" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/privacyPolicyLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_continue"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/errorRed"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPrivacyPolicy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:textColor="text"
            android:text="@string/fragment_terms_and_condition_privacy_policy" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button_continue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:background="@color/errorRed"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ELO"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How should I set constraint between this two parts of the view, so they wont overlap on small screen? Add `marginTop` to the bottom section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, will post below, maybe it helps someone in the future:

I copied all elements from Bottom section inside ScrollView:

```
  <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" >

      <!-- all LinearLayout's from bottom section -->

      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```